# What can yeoman's withGenerators test helper be used for?

Tags: javascript, testing, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I've been creating a lot of tests for yeoman generators lately, and I'm having trouble understanding the purpose of the `withGenerators()` [helper method](http://yeoman.io/generator/RunContext.html).

The example given:

```
var angular = new RunContext('../../app');
 angular.withGenerators([
   '../../common',
   '../../controller',
   '../../main',
   [helpers.createDummyGenerator(), 'testacular:app']
 ]);
```

The function itself:

```
RunContext.prototype.withGenerators = function (dependencies) {
  assert(_.isArray(dependencies), 'dependencies should be an array');
  this.dependencies = this.dependencies.concat(dependencies);
  return this;
};
```

I see that the function adds an array of dependencies to the Run Context object, with each item in the array being a path to a dependent generator.

What are these paths used for?

When and why would I need to use this method?

In the example given, is calling `angular.withGenerators([...])` identical to calling `yo angular`, `yo angular:common`, `yo angular:controller`, and so on from the command line, or does it somehow simulate or modify calls to `composeWith()` in the actual generator?

What is the difference between running `withGenerators()` in the tests, and calling `composeWith()` from the generator itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is used for `composeWith()` (or the legacy `invoke()` and `hookFor()` methods).

You can see the relevant code here: https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman-test/blob/master/lib/index.js#L173-L188

Basically when calling `composeWith()`, it'll use the dummy generator mock you passed instead of the one the environment would resolve.

A tricky part at the moment is that if you pass the `local` path settings to composeWith, it'll ignore the stubs - you can see the bug filled here https://github.com/yeoman/generator/issues/704 (the ticket suggests some manual workarounds)